# Row being skipped

Tags: php, mysql

I have checked all previous versions of this question and in those cases it was evident as to why it wasn't working but when I query my database it is returning no rows. There is only one row right now so I am completely confused as to why the query returns empty. Any advice would be helpful.

```
$prodSQL = "SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN shopPage ON products.storePage_id = shopPage.storePage_id 
    INNER JOIN gallery ON products.gallery_id = gallery.gallery_id 
    INNER JOIN image ON products.image_id = image.image_id WHERE products.storePage_id = ".$_GET['shop_id'];
    $productInfo = $conn->query($prodSQL)  or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error($prodSQL));
    $row = $productInfo->fetch_assoc();
    $gallery_id = $row['gallery_id'];
    $mainTitle = $row['storePage_title'];
    if($productInfo->num_rows === 0)
    {
        echo 'No results';
    }
    $productInfo->close();
```

Comment: if your query execute successfully but you got empty result because of inner join i think because when you use inner join it will give only that records which are match in both tables as per your condition

Comment: Your query return no rows.

Comment: @jilesh You sir are a saint. you were right, the gallery was missing and I am an idiot for missing that. Thank you!!!